# Prevent Visual Studio Code from activating the Python virtual environment

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code

With a Python project opened, whenever I open the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code it's automatically activating the virtual environment. I'm sure that's done by VS Code because I can find this command in the bash history of that terminal:

`source <project-directory>/venv/bin/activate`

I don't want the virtual environment to be activated. How can we prevent VS Code from doing that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Add `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` to your settings (globally to your user settings if you never want it, otherwise your `settings.json` file which is found in .vscode directory; this folder is found in your workspace directory if this is a per-workspace thing for you; [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)).

Comment: Omg thank you! This caused me so much headaches.

Comment: I feel like this is a bug, I'd expected that I should be able to use `F1 > Python Create Terminal` and it should source the project venv but `Terminal > Create Terminal` should just create a `bash` terminal. This setting disables both?

Comment: @DavidWaterworth https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21864

Comment: thanks @BrettCannon I've upvoted the issue

Answer (score 2):

In my case, setting `python.terminal.activateEnvironment` to false only didn't work.
I noticed that pyenv is activated on specific projects and not on others. This is due to previous use of the virtual environment on projects, even if they no longer exist or are not python projects.

You will therefore need to reset it by re-selecting the python interpreter:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P
2. Python: Select Interpreter
   [image]
3. Select the relevant project
4. Select the "Global" version of python
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you open the vscode terminal first and then select python interpreter, then it won't activate the python environment. This answer works in vscode 1.44.0 with pyhton 3.8.1. I haven't tested with other versions. However, if you have any files or workspace open you need to close that first to close the python interpreter. You don't need to make any changes in settings.