# How to stop conda activating environment after shell is opened

Tags: python, bash, conda, miniconda

I would like to set a default Conda environment for my (bash) shell as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28436769/6619692) and am trying to do this by appending the following to the end of my `.bashrc` (which I understand executes on opening each new terminal - please correct me if not).

```bash
conda activate myenv
```

I see the following on login:

```
(myenv) $ source /home/anil/miniconda3/bin/activate main
(main) $
```

This indicates that my environment was activated successfully but another script is being pasted into and run after the terminal is opened. Which conda file or artefact is responsible for this behaviour and how can I disable it, or modify it to set my preferred default shell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default Anaconda python environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment)

Comment: @ades No, you have linked the SO question that I refer to and link in my question

Answer (score 1):

This issue was not caused by my shell or conda, but rather by VSCode.

The issue was resolved by setting `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` in my settings, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54876747/6619692).

See also the documentation on [Python environment tools provided by VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).