# How to get vscode to use `conda activate` instead of `source activate`?

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda

When opening a new terminal in vscode, if I have

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
```

and I already selected a Python interpreter (see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802148/prevent-visual-studio-code-from-activating-the-python-virtual-environment) and documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)), then the terminal opens and automatically activates the environment using

```
source /path/to/the/environment/bin/activate /path/to/the/environment
```

I can turn this behavior off by setting `python.terminal.activateEnvironment` to false.

Of course, I can also manually activate the environment using

```
conda activate /path/to/the/environment
```

**How to get vscode to use `conda activate` automatically instead of `source activate`?**

Using `source` as vscode does sets the activated environment as the "base", e.g. if I do `conda env list` I will see something like:

```
conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                         /path/to/the/actual/base/environment
base                  *  /path/to/the/environment
```

and this causes some issues. For example, if I try to use `mamba` which I have in my "true" base environment but not in the other one, it will cause a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: The `bin/activate` is installed by the `conda` package. One should only have the `conda` package installed in **base**. Removing the `conda` package from the other environment might fix the behavior. Otherwise, the `bin/activate` is merely a shell script that literally runs `conda activate $@`.

Comment: @merv you are right. I had installed `conda-build` in order to use `conda develop .` However, instead of installing conda-build in my base environment, I did it within the project environment. After removing `conda` from the project environment I can confirm that vscode uses `conda activate` as expected.